# I have a canvas inside the div. How do I get it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Girl! Fly and eat the yogurt!</title>
    <script src="js/easeljs-0.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/particles.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #frame {
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "frame">
        <canvas class=" sketch" height="385" width="1440"></canvas>
    </div>
    <script src="js/particles.js"></script>
    <script>
        var canvas = $("#frame").get(0);
        canvas.id = "gameView";
    </script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Would you please tell me how to get the canvas inside the div using either jQuery or vanilla JS in this specific case? And how to set an id for the captured canvas element?

Comment: How do you get a reference to it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
```

Comment: @NoahSong Yup. Totally vanilla. Using jQuery it would be `$('canvas')[0]`.

Comment: @MikeC and @NoahSong - `$('canvas')[0]` would be a native html element. `$($('canvas')[0])` would be a jquery object (if desired)

Comment: @BrandtSolovij: A better way to get a jQuery object would be `$('canvas').eq(0)`.

Comment: document. getElementById("mycanvas") would also work if the canvas was given the ID "mycanvas"  first -  example in vanilla JS http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_measuretext